# How do i use this output value as a input

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to do math.random and put that value in this script

```js
let bday = Math.floor(
  Math.random() * (30 - 1 + 1) + 1
);
```

```
await test.page.select('select[name="day_select"]',bday);
```

but the problem is I need to add '' to bday, cuz if I do

```
await test.page.select('select[name="day_select"]','10');
```

it works, but this

```
await test.page.select('select[name="day_select"]',bday);
```

and this

```
await test.page.select('select[name="day_select"]','bday');
```

doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried using `bday.toString()` ?

Comment: Just do `''+bday` it will convert it to a string

Answer (score 0):

```
await test.page.select('select[name="day_select"]',`${bday}`);
```

I think this would work in your case.